# Is there any method to subtract two different date in python using strptime method

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

I'm using this code to subtract two different dates but I'm getting this error. any method or way?

> AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'z'

```py
def excelinput(day):
    loc = (day) 
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc) 
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 
    
    
    for i in range(sheet.nrows):
        if(i!=0):
            x = sheet.cell_value(i, 2)
            x = int(x * 24 * 3600)
            my_time = datetime.time(x//3600, (x%3600)//60)
            my_time1 = str(my_time)
            new_date0 = datetime.datetime.strptime(my_time1,"%H:%M:%S")
            z =new_date0.time()
            #print(za)
            hrStart = (time.z.strftime('%H'))
            minStart = (time.z.strftime('%M'))
            #print(hr+min)
            #print("start tym")
            start_time.append(z)
            
    for ii in range(sheet.nrows):
        if(ii!=0):
            c = sheet.cell_value(ii, 2)
            c = int(c * 24 * 3600)
            endtym = datetime.time(c//3600, (c%3600)//60)
            endtime = str(endtym)
            new_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(endtime,"%H:%M:%S")
            zz = new_date.time()
            hrEnd = (time.zz.strftime('%H'))
            minEnd = (time.zz.strftime('%M'))
            v=hrEnd-hrStart
            print(zz)
            print("mm--aaa")
            end_timearr.append(endtym)
```

Comment: The 2nd loop uses zz.  We would need to see your import statements.  Also, please provide a minimal example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .   Usually, you just use strptime to get two times, then subtract one from a another to get a timedelta.

Comment: ` import xlrd 
import time 
import datetime
import re
import schedule
import os`

Comment: this is my import statement

Comment: Great.  Please update your question with the import statement.  Make sure it works, then remove anything that is not essential to the problem.

Comment: not allowed to change code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I suggested to determine the difference between dates:

```
from datetime import datetime
dates = [ datetime.strptime(d, '%H:%M:%S') for d in ['12:13:14', '13:14:15']]
print(dates[1] - dates[0])
1:01:01
```

The two for loops  are quite similar, so suggest you refactor them to reduce duplication. Your code is not self-contained so it's difficult for me to rewrite it for you.